# combine multiple rows into 1 record in excel

Tags: excel

If I have excel table looks like this

```
ID  Description id1 id2 id3 id4
1   test        3           
1   test            4       
1   test                5   
1   test                    6
```

And I want to know a way to combine the all these 4 record become this one

```
ID|Description|id1|id2|id3|id4
1  test        3   4   5   6
```

How can I do that in Excel?

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere else in your workbook put the same columns and place the id(s) for which you want to retrieve those values. Use VLOOKUP(). The first parameter should be the id to look for, the second parameter is the table to take the data from, the third parameter is the column to take in the source table and the last parameter is usually 0 (case sensitive / insensitive flag).

Answer (score 0):

*For your example*, selecting the numbered id columns and:

Go To Special, Blanks then right-click and Delete... with Shift cells up only leaves you to delete the bottom three rows.